# How to convert shapefile/geojson to hexagons using uber h3 in python?

Tags: python, geojson, shapefile, h3

I want to create hexagons on my  geographic map and want to preserve the digital boundary specified by the shapefile/geojson as well.
How do I do it using uber's h3 python library?

I'm new to shapefiles or any other geographic data structures. I'm most comfortable with python.

Answer (score 18):

#### tl;dr

For convenience, you can use [H3-Pandas](https://github.com/DahnJ/H3-Pandas).

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import h3pandas

# Prepare data
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf['continent'].eq('Africa')]
gdf['gdp_md_per_capita'] = gdf['gdp_md_est'].div(gdf['pop_est'])
resolution = 4

# Resample to H3 cells
gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(resolution)
```

[image: africa-hexagons]

#### Full description

Use cases like this are precisely why I wrote [H3-Pandas](https://github.com/DahnJ/H3-Pandas), an integration of H3 with Pandas and GeoPandas.

Let's use the `naturalearth_lowres` dataset included in `GeoPandas` to demonstrate the usage.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import h3pandas

path_shapefile = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
gdf = gpd.read_file(path_shapefile)
```

Let's also create a numeric column for plotting.

```py
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf['continent'].eq('Africa')]
gdf['gdp_md_per_capita'] = gdf['gdp_md_est'].div(gdf['pop_est'])
```

```py
ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(15, 15), column='gdp_md_per_capita', cmap='RdBu')
ax.axis('off')
```

[image: africa]

We will use H3 resolution 4. See the [H3 resolution table](https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/restable/) for more details.

```py
resolution = 4
```

We can add H3 hexagons using the function [`polyfill`](https://h3-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/h3pandas.html#h3pandas.h3pandas.H3Accessor.polyfill). This method adds a list of H3 cells whose centroid falls into each polygon.

```py
gdf_h3 = gdf.h3.polyfill(resolution)
print(gdf_h3['h3_polyfill'].head(3))

1     [846aca7ffffffff, 8496b5dffffffff, 847b691ffff...
2     [84551a9ffffffff, 84551cdffffffff, 8455239ffff...
11    [846af51ffffffff, 8496e63ffffffff, 846a803ffff...
Name: h3_polyfill, dtype: object
```

If we want to explode the values horizontally (ending up with as many rows as there are H3 cells), we can use the parameter `explode`

```py
gdf_h3 = gdf.h3.polyfill(resolution, explode=True)
print(gdf_h3.head(3))

    pop_est continent      name iso_a3  gdp_md_est  \
1  53950935    Africa  Tanzania    TZA    150600.0   
1  53950935    Africa  Tanzania    TZA    150600.0   
1  53950935    Africa  Tanzania    TZA    150600.0   

                                            geometry  gdp_md_per_capita  \
1  POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1.05982...           0.002791   
1  POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1.05982...           0.002791   
1  POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1.05982...           0.002791   

       h3_polyfill  
1  846aca7ffffffff  
1  8496b5dffffffff  
1  847b691ffffffff
```

We can then utilize the method [`h3_to_geo_boundary`](https://h3-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/h3pandas.html#h3pandas.h3pandas.H3Accessor.h3_to_geo_boundary) to obtain the geometries for the H3 cells. It expects that the index already has the H3 cell ids.

```py
gdf_h3 = gdf_h3.set_index('h3_polyfill').h3.h3_to_geo_boundary()
```

We can now plot the result

```py
ax = gdf_h3.plot(figsize=(15, 15), column='gdp_md_per_capita', cmap='RdBu')
ax.axis('off')
```

[image: africa-hexagons]

H3-Pandas actually has convenience function that performs all this at once: [`polyfill_resample`](https://h3-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/h3pandas.html#h3pandas.h3pandas.H3Accessor.polyfill_resample)

```
gdf_h3 = gdf.h3.polyfill_resample(resolution)
ax = gdf_h3.plot(figsize=(15, 15), column='gdp_md_per_capita', cmap='RdBu')
ax.axis('off')
```

[image: africa-hexagons]

Answer (score 1):

`h3-py` doesn't know how to work with shapefile data directly, but it sounds like you could use a library like https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp to convert you shapefile data to GeoJSON, and then use `h3.polyfill()` to convert to a collection of H3 hexagons.

There are lots of options for plotting your boundary along with the H3 hexagons. For example, you might use [pydeck](https://pydeck.gl/) and its [GeoJsonLayer](https://pydeck.gl/gallery/geojson_layer.html) and [H3HexagonLayer](https://pydeck.gl/gallery/h3_hexagon_layer.html) layers.

If your plotting software can't use H3 hexagons directly, you can convert them to other formats with functions like `h3.h3_to_geo_boundary()` or `h3.h3_set_to_multi_polygon()`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a GeoJSON to Uber's h3 is quite simple.

Attaching a sample code snippet and GeoJSON used below:

**GeoJSON**:

`{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[77.5250244140625,13.00857192009273],[77.51266479492188,12.971103764892034],[77.52777099609375,12.94099133483504],[77.57171630859375,12.907528813968185],[77.60604858398438,12.914890953258695],[77.662353515625,12.928276105253065],[77.69874572753906,12.961066692801282],[77.65823364257812,13.00990996390651],[77.58956909179688,13.04469656691112],[77.53944396972656,13.038007215169166],[77.5250244140625,13.00857192009273]]]}}]}`

**Code:**

```
from h3converter import h3converter

geojson_raw = open("sampleJson.geojson",)
geojson = json.load(geojson_raw)

h3_list = []
h3_resolution = 7
for feature in geojson["features"]:
    feature_h3 = h3converter.polyfill(feature["geometry"], h3_resolution)
    h3_list.append(feature_h3)
    print("H3's created => ", len(feature_h3))

print(h3_list)
```

**Response:**

```
[{'8761892edffffff', '8760145b0ffffff', '87618925effffff', '87618925bffffff', '87618924affffff', '876189256ffffff', '8760145b1ffffff', '8761892eaffffff', '8761892eeffffff', '876189253ffffff', '876189259ffffff', '8760145b2ffffff', '876014586ffffff', '8760145b4ffffff', '8761892e1ffffff', '8760145a2ffffff', '8761892ecffffff', '876189251ffffff', '8760145a4ffffff', '8761892e5ffffff', '87618925affffff', '8761892e9ffffff', '8761892cdffffff', '876189250ffffff', '87618925dffffff', '8760145b6ffffff', '876014595ffffff', '876189252ffffff', '8761892ebffffff', '8760145a3ffffff', '8760145a6ffffff', '876014584ffffff', '876189258ffffff', '8760145b5ffffff', '8760145b3ffffff', '876014594ffffff', '8761892c9ffffff', '87618925cffffff', '8760145a0ffffff', '8761892e8ffffff'}]
```

**Package used:** https://pypi.org/project/h3converter/

You could use the above package to convert h3 to GeoJSON as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can extract GeoJSON from Shapley like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

# Create Geometry
shapely_polygon = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)])

# Extract JSON Feature Collection
gpd.GeoSeries([shapely_polygon]).__geo_interface__
```

**Output:**

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"id":"0","type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0],[1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]]]},"bbox":[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]}],"bbox":[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]}
```